# Webodf display odf from bytes

Tags: c#, byte, odt, odf, webodf

Is it possible for webodf to read a odf / odt file from its bytes? instead of an url?

Currently using:

```
var odfelement = document.getElementById("odf");
var odfcanvas = new odf.OdfCanvas(odfelement);

odfcanvas.load("url/to/file.odt");
```

and would like something like

```
odfcanvas.loadFromBytes(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to read an odt file from byte Array and then load it in webodf editor.

1. To do so ,you will have to use javascript blob objects to construct a file from a byte array(desired file in bytes format).
2. Then you can get a temporary url for that blob object which is very similar to a file itself.The *'url'* is temporary url created and stored in browser.
3. Once you have the url for your file ( bytes => blob => getUrl ) then you can easily load the file in your webodf editor using '*openDocumentFromUrl*' function.

---

```
  var file = new Blob([data], {type: mimeType});
  // data  => your bytes file
  // mimeType => the mimetype of file(odt : application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text)

  var myUrl= URL.createObjectURL(file);
  // get the temorary url from blob object.

  editor.openDocumentFromUrl(myUrl, function(){});

  // editor is the active webodf context object which you get when webodf context is created
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using WebAPIs to push out the file stream. Seems you could setup a shim service to much the same? Else there might be some info to glean form the local editor (as it must do an upload of some form)?

Which I could help more, but I'm new to WebODF myself and thus far it's been a bit... obtuse ;)